# Using a cell string to query row values from Matlab structure.

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, indexing

Using a cell string to query row values from Matlab structure.

I have some stock market data, that look like this. The first column contains the field names in the structure:

```
Symbol     Price   Volume   Expiry
  AA         5       10     2002-2-3
  AA         6       11     2002-2-3
  FF         8       36     2002-1-5
  FF         2       36     2002-1-5                 
  ZZ         1       21     2002-5-4
```

I need to efficiently query the values of "Price", "Volume", and "Expiry", given a specific "Symbol", such as AA.

Desired output looking like:

```
    Symbol     Price   Volume   Expiry
      AA         5       10     2002-2-3
      AA         6       11     2002-2-3
```

I have a list of all the unique symbols and need to repeat this process for the whole list.

I have to do this on a huge set of data, and the structures contains a few million rows deep. I was wondering if anyone knew an efficient way to querying this data. Should I even be using structures?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Store data in a `dataset()` or table and apply `ismember()` to Symbol against your list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be fairly quick in terms of search speed, but I can't make any promises for actual performance with your data and Cell arrays, you'll just have to try it.

If you don't already have your data in a Cell array, you can populate the array programmatically, but for illustration lets set up some data manually:

```
A = {'AA', 'AA', 'FF', 'FF', 'ZZ' ;
     5,6,8,2,1; 10,11,36,36,21; 
     '2002-2-3', '2002-2-3', '2002-1-5', '2002-1-5', '2002-5-4'};
```

Take B as the transpose:

```
B = A'

B = 
    'AA'    [5]    [10]    '2002-2-3'
    'AA'    [6]    [11]    '2002-2-3'
    'FF'    [8]    [36]    '2002-1-5'
    'FF'    [2]    [36]    '2002-1-5'
    'ZZ'    [1]    [21]    '2002-5-4'
```

Then you can use your search string like this:

```
searchString = 'AA';
indx = find( ismember(B(:,1), searchString) );
result = B(indx,:)

result = 
    'AA'    [5]    [10]    '2002-2-3'
    'AA'    [6]    [11]    '2002-2-3'
```

You can then access the individual values of your query like this:

```
>> [result{1,2} result{1,3}]
ans =
     5    10
```